# Mathematical background to understand the Pdf format specification?

Tags: pdf, math

I would like to comprehend the pdf internal structure. It is my understanding that the pdf format is described within the adobe Pdf reference(currently 3rd edition).
However, It will be very difficult to interpret what's in it, since it contains a lot of mathematical principles.

What are the requirements(mathematics/programming) before I can actually try reading the documentation?

Comment: is there a specific section that is hard to interpret, or which is representative? clicking around at random i'm not seeing where the mathy stuff is. except it looks like for some sections you need some linear algebra.

Comment: "What are the requirements(mathematics/programming) before I can actually try reading the documentation?" There are none. Nothing is preventing you from trying to read the documentation. If and when you find a specific thing that you don't understand, at that stage you can ask a much more focused question (perhaps on [mathematics.se] if it is a strict math question, perhaps here if it is a programming question).

Comment: Also, the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdf/info) for the `pdf` tag links to some helpful sources for understanding the format.

Comment: Shouldn't I need some image processing or computer graphics background for all those chapters discussing rendering? Then there's the part about the various compression algorithms just to name a few;

Comment: Part of the problem is that math is vast. If you get side-tracked in learning the math before you start to learn what you want, you might never really start. Just take the plunge. In effect, the documentation itself will implicitly answer your question. But, that answer is scattered throughout the text as opposed to neatly laid out in a preface. I can relate: I am currently trying to learn some Biopython, despite no real biology background. I would probably lose interest in biopython if I tried to first wade through a text in molecular biology. Instead, I fill in what gaps I can as they arise.

Answer (score 1):

> It is my understanding that the pdf format is described within the adobe Pdf reference(currently 3rd edition).

That's not entirely correct. The PDF Reference third edition dates back to December 2001. In the following years a number of newer editions were published until in 2008 Adobe passed the rulership over the format on to ISO, ISO 32000-1 being the resulting specification of PDF. In 2017 this specification was updated to ISO 32000-2.

Adobe has published its PDF References and a copy of ISO 32000-1 (with changed page headers) on its web site, cf. https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

> What are the requirements(mathematics/programming) before I can actually try reading the documentation?

High school math, if taught well, can suffice. One semester of undergraduate math studies must suffice. The specification does not (for the most part) require any specific programming skills.

For an understanding of color spaces a well-founded knowledge of optics can be helpful.

The PDF specification references some external documents for some specifics. These external documentations may require a higher degree of knowledge in a number of subjects.

---

In principle @John in his comment is right: Simply start reading. When stuck try to learn using Google, Wikipedia, etc. If still stuck, ask on the appropriate stack exchange site.

Without any basic knowledge to start with, though, this can be very trying.

Comment: Good answer, though you might be a tad optimistic about high school math sufficing.

Comment: *"you might be a tad optimistic about high school math sufficing."* - Probably. Probably I'm getting old and forgot how that was... ;)